# Passing variable from within while loop to popupdiv

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables, input

I have table which displays the values of SQL table. In each row there is a dropdown which allows you to select which action you want to do. When you select the action and click '
go', it pops up a form which I want to be able to pass the $id variable from the table to the popup div form, then on to the next pop page. ID displays correctly in dropdown, but whenever when it shows the div, its showing the incorrect id (its displaying the first id of the table, rather than the id of the selected dropdown).

Heres the php

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($proposal_result)) {
            $date=substr($row["date"], 0, 50);
            $formatted_date=date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date));
            $id=substr($row["idproposal"], 0, 50);
            $businessname=substr($row["businessname"], 0, 50);
            $status=substr($row["status"], 0, 50);
            $staff=substr($row["staff"], 0, 50);
            $file_access='<bucket-location>';
            $file_name='proposal_'.$id.'_'.$businessname.'.pdf';
            $file=$file_access.$file_name;
            print "<tr><td>".$formatted_date."</<td>
            <td>".$id."</td>
            <td width='25px'><a href='".$file."'target='_blank'><img src='".$images."/attachment.png' alt='file'></a></td>
            <td>".$businessname."</td><td>".$staff."</td>
            <td>".$status."</td>
            <td>
                    <div>
                        <select id='zb-admin-dropdown' name='zb-admin-dropdown' class='dropdowns'  required>
                            <option value='0'>Select and action...*</option>
                            <option value='1'>Change Status for ID#".$id."</option>
                            <option value='2'>Delete Proposal</option>
                        </select>
                    <input type='submit' id='report-submit' value='Go' onclick='displayDiv()'></div>

                    </td></tr>";
        }
```

Javascript

```
function displayDiv() {
    e=document.getElementById("zb-admin-dropdown");
    strUser=e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    if (strUser=='1') {
        document.getElementById('abc').style.display = "block";     
    }
    if (strUser=='2') {
        document.getElementById('def').style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

popupdiv

```
print "<div id='abc'>
                <div id='popup'>
                    <form name='changestatus' action='' method='post'>
                        <!--<img id='close' src='images/3.png'> CLOSE ICON-->
                        <h2>Change Status for ".$id."</h2>
                        <hr>
                        <textarea name='deletecomments' placeholder='Comments...'></textarea><br />
                        <a href='/delete?id=".$id."&businessname=".$businessname."'><input type='button' id='report-submit' value='Delete Proposal'></a><a href='/zerobooks-admin-dashboard'><input type='button' id='report-submit' value='Cancel'></a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>";
print "<div id='def'>
                <div id='popup'>
                    <form name='deletefeedback' action='' method='post'>
                        <!--<img id='close' src='images/3.png'> CLOSE ICON-->
                        <h2>Reason for deleting proposal <br />".$id."</h2>
                        <hr>
                        <input id='deletereason' type='radio' name='deletereason' class='radio' value='Added by mistake'>Added by mistake<br />
                        <input id='deletereason' type='radio' name='deletereason' class='radio' value='Added by mistake'>No longer required<br />
                        <input id='deletereason' type='radio' name='deletereason' class='radio' value='Added by mistake'>Incorrect Information Provided<br />
                        <input id='deletereason' type='radio' name='deletereason' class='radio' value='Added by mistake'>Reason 4<br />
                        <textarea name='deletecomments' placeholder='Comments...'></textarea><br />
                        <a href='/delete?id=".$id."&businessname=".$businessname."'><input type='button' id='report-submit' value='Delete Proposal'></a><a href='/zerobooks-admin-dashboard'><input type='button' id='report-submit' value='Cancel'></a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>";
```

My aim is pretty much to pass the correct ID to the popupdiv. Any help would be appreciated. You can ignore the content of the popupdiv forms.

Comment: You have multiple `<select>`s with id="zb-admin-dropdown" on your page. That's invalid, IDs have to be unique.

Comment: Are you adding the same ID for all selects? i.e. zb-admin-dropdown if so then this is at least part of your problem. You need to give them a unique ID otherwise how does the computer know which one you mean.

Comment: Yes, this was one of my issues. This has fixed my issue partially. The second issue was solved via the below solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your html, you call the function when a button is clicked.  Pass the variable there in the function call. So:

```
<input type='submit' id='report-submit' value='Go' onclick='displayDiv(' + $id + ')'></div>
```

Then have the javascript function accept an input:

```
function displayDiv(divId) { ...
```

and use it in the javascript.  But the thing is, php is server side, and javascript is client side.  So to get the information to the server-side php, you need to make an http request.

I can't see where all the code is but you may be able to try a couple work-arounds with minimal refactoring.  First, after the div element is displayed, you can have the javascript update the `href` tag with:

```
 `document.getElementById(/*a_element's_id*/).href=''+divId`
```

Otherwise, I'm  not a php expert, but I think perhaps if the php scripts are in the same scope, a global variable or perhaps a global static variable would be accessible to both php scripts?

Personally I'd go all javscript! :)
Best of luck